# Why is my program to find prime numbers within a range not working the way it's supposed to

Tags: java, logic-error

I tried creating a program to find prime numbers within a range. The user is asked to input two numbers then the goal of the program will be to print out the prime numbers between the first number and the last number.

Here's my code below:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // program to check prime numbers b/w two numbers
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        byte factorsCount = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
        int numOne = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
        int numTwo = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("The prime numbers are: ");

        for (int i = numOne+1; i < numTwo; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                if (i%j == 0) {
                    factorsCount++;
                }
            }
            if (factorsCount == 2) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the program is not working as intended. For some numOne and numTwo it prints some prime numbers whilst for others it prints nothing

The way I intended for it to work is as follows:

1. It asks the user for the first number and the second number. It then creates a variable to store the no. of factors a specific number has
2. The outer for loop iterates through the numbers between the first and second number
3. The inner for loop counts the number of factors a number has
4. After the inner loop is done, it breaks out of the inner loop then checks if the factorsCount is equal to 2. if yes, then it is a prime number hence it prints it out and if no it just goes to the next number within the range
5. It repeats steps one through four until it has exhausted the numbers within the Range after which it must have printed all the prime numbers

Comment: Where do you reset factorsCount?

Comment: A number can always be divided by itself, so what should `j` stop at?

Comment: _"For some numOne and numTwo it prints some prime numbers whilst for others it prints nothing"_ - How about providing some examples.

Comment: Instead of counting factors, why not just stop when you have a factor other than 1 or the value under test?

Comment: And just in case it isn't clear, the very first comment by WJS has pinpointed the bug.

Comment: as the first comment mentioned, you must reset factorsCount before starting (or after the end of) the inner loop; otherwise it will probably only work correctly for the first iteration of the outer loop (`i = numOne+1`) || BTW there is no advantage in using, or reason to use `byte` for that variable.

Comment: You can be more efficient in your prime number checking. You just need to check if %2 == 0 or find *one* *odd* number between 3 and sqrt(num) divides evenly (%oddnum == 0)

Comment: But most importantly, the cause of your problem and its solution would probably be apparent if you did some debugging of your code, and this is a skill that you will want to learn. If you're not sure about how to do this, please check out the [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) link.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that `factorsCount` is likely to overflow if the number has too many factors. This may lead to false positives

Comment: There are many improvements you can make to  this.  I recommend you search this site using `primes` as a key word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working copy of your code

```
package com.goodyear;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // program to check prime numbers b/w two numbers
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        byte factorsCount = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
        int numOne = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
        int numTwo = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("The prime numbers are: ");

        for (int i = numOne+1; i < numTwo; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                if (i%j == 0) {
                    factorsCount++;
                }
            }
            if (factorsCount == 2) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
            factorsCount = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Resetting the `factorCount` variable after evaluation allows for the next evaluation to occur as designed. Also, consider making you evaluation inclusive on `numOne` and `numTwo` by changing your loop variables.

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution. The thing is that it needs within that range which excludes numOne and numTwo

Comment: In that case, you may disregard my suggestion to include both ends of the range

Answer (score 0):

@Paul Stoner write you your code that's work.

I suggest an optimization.

1. Don't need to check all numbers in range, just odd, so start the outer loop with the first odd after `numOne` and increment by 2, implicit excluding all evens
2. Don't need to check 1 and itself as divisor, we know that all number are always divisible by 1 and itself, so exclude it from inner loop.
3. Don't need to check all divisor, you need to find first odd (because if a number can be divided by an even is even itself and it's excluded on top). At the first occurrence, you number are not prime, so you can exit.

in this way

```
private static void findPrimes(int start, int end) {
    for (int number = start % 2 == 0 ? start + 1 : start + 2; number <= end; number += 2) {
        boolean hasDivisor = false;
        for (int divisor = 3; divisor < number && !hasDivisor; divisor+=2) {
            hasDivisor = number % divisor == 0;
        }
        if (!hasDivisor) {
            System.out.println(number);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I tested my code, as the OP wrote it, and it worked just fine.